# Блокировка скролла body на iOS, при открытом попапе

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

Есть проблема: нужно блокировать скролл body, при открытом попапе, **при этом сам попап нужно скроллить т.к. контента там много !**
Пробовал навешивать на body класс

```
`popup__opened {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}`
```

И этот вариант прекрасно работает на десктопах! Но не на **iOS(iPhone / iPad)**
Если я задам height: 100vh - safari проигнорит и это.
Еще пробовал навесить на body position: fixed; - этот вариант тоже не подходит - при закрытии попапа пользователя скроллит к верху страницы.

Как решить эту проблему? (Попапов много, открываются по кнопкам, расположенных в разных блоках)

Comment: Попробуйте [вот это](https://github.com/FL3NKEY/scroll-lock). У меня аналогичная проблема, но данный метод еще не опробывал. Отпишитесь если сработает

Comment: @E_K пробовал, не подходит\ выдает странные ошибки в некоторых случаях

Comment: @E_K Заюзай код книзу

Comment: @E_K page__wrapper это обертка для всего сайта. можешь добавлять класс body, поюзай, посмотри как работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
нашёл решение которое работает в моем случае:

    $(".js-popup").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        windowOffsetTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        $(".page__wrapper").css("top", -windowOffsetTop)
        $(".page__wrapper").addClass("popup__opened");
        $(".popup").show();
    })
    $(".popup__close").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".page__wrapper").removeClass("popup__opened");
        $(".popup").hide();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: windowOffsetTop
        }, 0);
    })
```

```css
    .popup__opened {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
    }
```